# What is the end of credits song for Hunter x Hunter season 1 episode 51?

Tags: music, hunter-x-hunter

At the end of *Hunter x Hunter* season 1 episode 51 (AxBrutalxBattlefield), they play a different classical credits song instead of "Hunting for Your Dream". It plays right after Mozart's "Lacrimosa".

What is the name of the song?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J-Yg9N-q0Ok It's called 'Riot'.

---

Source:

- https://www.reddit.com/r/anime/comments/5v7i77/rewatch_hunter_x_hunter_2011_episode_51/